# How can I avoid getting a 502 Gateway Error while restarting php-fpm?

Tags: php, nginx

When restarting the php-fpm service on my Linux system, the PHP CGI process take a while to shutdown completely. Until it does, trying to start a new PHP CGI instance fails because port 9000 is still held by the terminating process. Accessing the site during this time results in a 502 Gateway Error, which I'd like to avoid.

How can I restart php-fpm smoothly without getting this error?

Comment: Do you do php-fpm restart via restart or reload command option? In theory graceful reload shouldn't throw any errors at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Run two instances of php-fpm, describe it in one [upstream](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpUpstreamModule) section.

```
    upstream fast_cgi {
        server localhost:9000;
        server localhost:9001 backup;
    }
```

Change nginx.conf, to use `fastcgi_pass fast_cgi;`.
After that, if you restart one instance, nginx will process request through second php-fpm instance.